# what can I use as a flag in an int array in c++?

Tags: c++

what should I put in an int array to be different from the other quantities?I mean somthing that I could use as a flag.can I use null

Comment: what kind of integers will be stored in the array? Why do you need a flag?

Comment: What is the range of values that you plan on storing in the array? If the range is unknown it's probably a bad idea to just pick a number.

Comment: I use this array for a calculator that contains all numbers.I want a flag that shows there is a sign such as +,- or * after a number.

Comment: does NULL change to 0 in an int array?if write it make a problem for me.

Comment: @zahra: It doesn't "change"; it is already a shortcut for one of several things, one of which is `0`. It is not some magical placeholder entity, except when it evaluates to `nullptr`.

Comment: Specifically, `NULL` is a macro which expands to an integer constant expression with value 0. So the following are possible things that `NULL` might be: `0`, `0L`, `(1-1)`. The latter of course is unlikely. The following are *not* permitted as expansions of `NULL`: `(void*)0`, `nullptr`. The most important property of `NULL` is that when you convert it to any pointer type you get a null pointer. The fact that it's required to have integral type ensures that since it doesn't have type `void*`, C++ unlike C doesn't need implicit conversion from `void*` to all pointer types.

Comment: @SteveJessop C++11 18.2/3: "The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard
(4.10)." 4.10/1: "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`." So yes, `NULL` could be defined to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is not special.  When assigned to an `int`, `NULL` simply is evaluated as `0`.

An `int` can only contain integral values.  There is no "on/off" bit on an `int` to indicate if it has a value.  An `int` **always** has a value (sometimes uninitialized, but that's another thing)

Whether or not you can use `NULL` (and hence `0`) as a special flag depends on you and your program.  Is `0` a legitimate value for this `int`?  If so, you can't use it.  You'll have to find another way.

One other way would be to use something like `optional` from Boost.  An `optional` is a class template, which can contain your `int`.  It also contains a boolean flag which indicates if it "has" the `int` value.  Here's a sample use case:

```
optional <int> v;  // not initialized yet

assert (!v);  // assert that it hasn't got a value yet
v = 41; // now give it a value
assert (v);  // assert that is has a value now
const int savedValue = *v;  // get the assigned value
assert (savedValue == 42);
```

If you don't have or want Boost, [here is an implementation](http://ideone.com/FeFRWP) of `optional` along with a little test harness.

Answer (score 1):

Only you can answer that, by deciding which value(s) can never be "valid" in your application.

In C++, the expression `NULL` is not a magical "this has no value" thing — sometimes it is equivalent to `0` but even then that is not necessarily an "invalid" value in your application.

It may be that you're better off marking unused indexes in another way, either with a list of unused indexes, or by using a container like `std::set` and simply not having the unused values in the first place.